# How to download a file securely using django rest framework? I am making using of Oauth2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am creating a Django rest api and making use of Oauth2 for authentication and token generation. I need information about downloading any file using REST api securely. How can i achieve this.

Below is my serialized data and i want to download the "document" i.e "link_mh6f7d3.db" using get request securely.

{
        "id": 5,
        "file_name": "sqlite3",
        "file_descripton": "upload sqlite3 dump file",
        "completed": true,
        "upload_time": "2017-05-08T12:57:59.457859Z",
        "document": "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:9000/media/Documents/link_mh6f7d3.db"
    },

currently i am requesting like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Documents/link_O1JBJGR.db  [but this is not secured]

Please shed some light on this topic.

Thanks, 
Shash

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that you are already using Token authentication. Why don't use `authentication_classes` decorator?